# how to execute Nunit test from command prompt without using nunit-console.exe?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, automated-tests

Is there a way to run Nunit test though at batch file or a service without the added dependency of installing Nunit-console.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NUnit, you can run tests using the nunit-console utility from your build script. But, this test runner just shows the results in a console window and saves a report in an XML file.You can try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37846/Check-NUnit-test-results-from-a-batch-script) link.

Comment: Thank you but I am aware of added features of Nunit, but i already have functionality to send out emails via my unit test, however I would want to run these tests as basic console application on server where I would not want to install any softwares. So would it be possible to just run these tests as a simple .Net console app?

Answer (score -1):

To run your tests through the Nunit console, follow the command below:
running Nunit from the regular console:

nunit3-console.exe ".\jobmidia\Unick.dll" --result="jobmidiaresult.xml;format=nunit3" --work=".\FormularioResultados" --where "cat=paralelo"
ReportUnit.exe ".\FormularioResultados" ".\FormularioHTMLReport"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.